# Resize eraser tool does not work Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration

Why can't I change the size of eraser tool in Illustrator? I select it and I press the brackets **[ ]** and it does not work, the size is the same always. Any idea?

Comment: It works here for me. Couple things; make sure you are using the Eraser tool (Shift+E) and not the Path Eraser tool first off. Try a restart of illi... and also your computer ?

Comment: Thanks man! It worked!